# Sass gem not running after macOS Catalina upgrade

Tags: sass, rubygems

After upgrading to macOS Catalina, my Sass gem stopped working. Originally, I installed it using `gem install sass`, but now, it doesn't appear under `gem list`. I read another thread that suggested re-installing Sass in the ~ directory with Homebrew, but before trying that, I want to check if I actually need to.

When I navigate to my /Library/Ruby/Gems/ folder, I can see Sass in:

1. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.23
2. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.1
3. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-listen-4.0.0

Also, I still have sass, sass-convert, and scss in /usr/local/bin.

`sass -v` returns `zsh: /usr/local/bin/sass: bad interpreter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: no such file or directory`.

Is Sass actually still installed and just not linked properly? I haven't tried installing it via Homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue, and you're correct in thinking it's not linked properly.

I reinstalled using Homebrew: `brew install sass/sass/sass`.

I then run `brew link sass` to fix the link issue.

If it complains the link already exists, you can override it using `brew link --overwrite sass`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Before I try this, did you originally install Sass through Homebrew? I'm not sure if I n did 'cause it doesn't appear under `brew list`. I just don't want to end up with multiple installations.

Comment: @MarioParra I did install it originally through Homebrew yes. However, if possible I recommend you switch from Ruby Sass as it was deprecated a few months back. See here: https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass

Comment: Thanks for the tip! While your sass wasn't unlinked, did it still appear under `brew list`?

Comment: This solution worked for me. Though instead of forcing the link I opted to manually run `rm '/usr/local/bin/sass` then `brew link sass`

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue with Ruby ​​Sass after upgrading to macOS Catalina.
I reinstalled the Xcode Command Line Tools and also reinstalled Ruby ​Sass.

```
(sudo) gem install sass
```

This worked fine for me!